Generating EIP 712 Signature from Polymarket
I am trying to generate EIP-712 to be used for L1 Header in Polymarket. Unfortunately I am unable to correctly generate the code due to errors.
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Wallet } from '@ethersproject/wallet'
import { buildClobEip712Signature } from '@/utils/polymarket/eip712'
import { Chain } from '@/types'

const privateKey =
  '0x*************'
const wallet = new Wallet(privateKey)

const chainId = Chain.AMOY
const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
const nonce = 23

buildClobEip712Signature(wallet, chainId, timestamp, nonce)
  .then(signature => {
    console.log('Signature:', signature)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error generating signature:', error)
  })
</script>

This is the code for buildClobEip712Signature
/**
 * Builds the canonical Polymarket CLOB EIP712 signature
 * @param signer
 * @param ts
 * @returns string
 */
export const buildClobEip712Signature = async (
  signer: Wallet | JsonRpcSigner,
  chainId: Chain,
  timestamp: number,
  nonce: number,
): Promise<string> => {
  const address = await signer.getAddress()
  const ts = `${timestamp}`

  const domain = {
    name: 'ClobAuthDomain',
    version: '1',
    chainId: chainId,
  }

  const types = {
    ClobAuth: [
      { name: 'address', type: 'address' },
      { name: 'timestamp', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'nonce', type: 'uint256' },
      { name: 'message', type: 'string' },
    ],
  }
  const value = {
    address,
    timestamp: ts,
    nonce,
    message: MSG_TO_SIGN,
  }

  const sig = await signer._signTypedData(domain, types, value)
  return sig
}

This code is referenced to Github: https://github.com/Polymarket/clob-client/blob/main/src/signing/eip712.ts
From what I understood. I need the private_key and public_address which are used for encoding POLY_SIGNATURE (which I have). Basically what I understood in graph is this
Generate EIP 712 Signature -> L1 -> polymarket/api/api-key -> L2 -> polymarket/api/*
The error the I am facing. This line what causes the run time error for some reason when I call the chain const chainId = Chain.AMOY
constants.ts:43 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from')
    at node_modules/@polymarket/order-utils/node_modules/@ethereumjs/util/dist/constants.js (constants.ts:43:38)
    at __require2 (chunk-PLDDJCW6.js?v=d0082a35:17:50)
    at node_modules/@polymarket/order-utils/node_modules/@ethereumjs/util/dist/index.js (index.ts:4:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-PLDDJCW6.js?v=d0082a35:17:50)
    at node_modules/@polymarket/order-utils/node_modules/@metamask/eth-sig-util/dist/personal-sign.js (personal-sign.ts:1:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-PLDDJCW6.js?v=d0082a35:17:50)
    at node_modules/@polymarket/order-utils/node_modules/@metamask/eth-sig-util/dist/index.js (index.ts:1:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-PLDDJCW6.js?v=d0082a35:17:50)
    at node_modules/@polymarket/order-utils/dist/exchange.order.builder.js (exchange.order.builder.ts:1:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-PLDDJCW6.js?v=d0082a35:17:50)


You mention errors.  Please edit the question to include the exact errors you're facing.
